# Visual Studio T4 - include file using environment variable

Tags: macros, include, environment-variables, t4

I have some T4 templates set up which reference other shared T4s. One T4 references another like this:

<#@ include file="%MTF%\DAL\Models\DALContextGenerator.tt"#>

This works fine except MTF has to be defined as an environment variable at the operating system level - I want to define this somewhere in the solution itself - or in each project within the solution if I have to. I've tried editing the CSPROJ file and adding an entry under , but the T4 engine doesn't seem to pick that up. I also tried creating a C++ property sheet and adding it there as a macro, but again the T4 engine (from inside a C# project) can't see it either.

Thanks in advance for any tips,

Ray

Comment: Is %MTF% relative to your project/solution?  If so, you can use VS Macros instead of environment variables, e.g. $(SolutionDir) etc.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not- I am using $(SolutionDir) elsewhere though so I knwo about that but a good tip. In this case MTF is a reference to another solution where I'm keeping common T4 files which will be referenced by multiple solutions.

Comment: You can put the specified path in an XML/text file.

Comment: @vaibhav - thanks for the suggestion. However, I believe the include directive is processed at compile time so I don't believe I can generate the file name from an expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid there is no way to do this in the current version of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it myself, but in the Visual Studio documentation there is a [section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/t4-include-directive#msbuild) on how to use project properties in T4 include directives: